# Java printing database records on separate lines

Tags: java, mysql, database, string, jdbc

I have a JDBC program that takes records from a MySQL database and prints out the results. The user can select which results they want from the database by selecting different checkboxes to only display certain results.

Here is the method which gets the records and prints them out:

```
private void execute() throws SQLException {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM customers";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    String result = "";
    while (rs.next()) {
        if (cb1.isSelected()) {
            int custid = rs.getInt("custid");
            result += custid + " ";
        }
        if (cb2.isSelected()) {
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            result += name + " ";
        }
        if (cb3.isSelected()) {
            String address = rs.getString("address");
            result += address + " ";
        }
        if (cb4.isSelected()) {
            String city = rs.getString("city");
            result += city + " ";
        }
        if (cb5.isSelected()) {
            String state = rs.getString("state");
            result += state + " ";
        }
        if (cb6.isSelected()) {
            int zip = rs.getInt("zip");
            result += zip + " ";
        }
        // print the results
    }
    System.out.println(result);
    results.setText(result);

    stmt.close();
}
```

Currently, if I were to select say the first three checkboxes, I would get the output:

```
1 Smith, Tim 12 Elm St 2 Jones, Tom 435 Oak Dr 3 Avery, Bill 623 Ash Ave 4 Kerr, Debra 1573 Yew Crt
```

However, the output I am after is:

```
1, Smith, Tim, 12 Elm St
2, Jones, Tom, 435 Oak Dr
3, Avery, Bill, 623 Ash Ave
4, Kerr, Debra, 1573 Yew Crt
```

Is there any way I can add a new line after each record in the database, as well as maybe the commas in between items in each record? I am new to JDBC and MySQL connectivity, so any help or tips is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can print every single result just before the end of while loop, then it'll print every record in new line.

```
private void execute() throws SQLException {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM customers";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    String result = "";
    String singleResult = "";
    while (rs.next()) {
        if (cb1.isSelected()) {
            int custid = rs.getInt("custid");
            singleResult += custid + " ";
        }
        if (cb2.isSelected()) {
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            singleResult += name + " ";
        }
        if (cb3.isSelected()) {
            String address = rs.getString("address");
            singleResult += address + " ";
        }
        if (cb4.isSelected()) {
            String city = rs.getString("city");
            singleResult += city + " ";
        }
        if (cb5.isSelected()) {
            String state = rs.getString("state");
            singleResult += state + " ";
        }
        if (cb6.isSelected()) {
            int zip = rs.getInt("zip");
            singleResult += zip + " ";
        }
        System.out.println(singleResult);
        result +=singleResult;
    }
    //System.out.println(result);
    results.setText(result);

    stmt.close();
}
```

Or you can append line separator, just before closing while loop

```
System.out.println(singleResult);
result +=singleResult;
result +="\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would use a `StringJoiner` to gather the elements. Then, I would eliminate the many local temporary variables. Finally, I would use `println` in the loop and another `StringJoiner` for the final `result`. Like,

```
private void execute() throws SQLException {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM customers";
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    StringJoiner result = new StringJoiner(System.lineSeparator());
    while (rs.next()) {
        StringJoiner lineJoiner = new StringJoiner(", ");
        if (cb1.isSelected()) {
            lineJoiner.add(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("custid")));
        }
        if (cb2.isSelected()) {
            lineJoiner.add(rs.getString("name"));
        }
        if (cb3.isSelected()) {
            lineJoiner.add(rs.getString("address"));
        }
        if (cb4.isSelected()) {
            lineJoiner.add(rs.getString("city"));
        }
        if (cb5.isSelected()) {
            lineJoiner.add(rs.getString("state"));
        }
        if (cb6.isSelected()) {
            lineJoiner.add(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("zip")));
        }
        System.out.println(lineJoiner);
        result.add(lineJoiner.toString());
    }
    results.setText(result.toString());
    stmt.close();
}
```

You could also do the same thing with `Collection`(s) like,

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM customers";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
List<String> msg = new ArrayList<>();
while (rs.next()) {
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
    if (cb1.isSelected()) {
        al.add(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("custid")));
    }
    if (cb2.isSelected()) {
        al.add(rs.getString("name"));
    }
    if (cb3.isSelected()) {
        al.add(rs.getString("address"));
    }
    if (cb4.isSelected()) {
        al.add(rs.getString("city"));
    }
    if (cb5.isSelected()) {
        al.add(rs.getString("state"));
    }
    if (cb6.isSelected()) {
        al.add(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("zip")));
    }
    String line = al.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    System.out.println(line);
    msg.add(line);
}
results.setText(msg.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));
stmt.close();
```

Prefer whichever you find most *readable*.

Comment: Quick question. In my JavaFX TextField box (where this eventually has to be printed out, rather than just the console) it is still all on one line, Is there a way to correct this using the provided code?

Comment: @MatthewThibodeau Change `System.lineSeperator()` to `"<br/>"`

Comment: I fixed it by changing the TextField to a Label, and set the vBox it was in to have a Centered alignment. This worked for me. Thank you all for your help!